# PostgreSQL - Updating a column value based on another value

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, sql-update

I have been trying to accomplish an automatic update of a table based on a column value. Here is the example. The idea is that the user will enter their phone, but not their country like this:

| mobile_phone | country |
| --- | --- |
| '51682815' |  |
| '51261728' |  |
| '56682815' |  |
| '56261728' |  |
| '57682815' |  |
| '57261728' |  |

Based on the "*mobile_phone*" information I want to assign their country automatically with this logic:

- WHERE left(mobile_phone,2) = '51' then 'PE'
- WHERE left(mobile_phone,2)='56' then 'CL'
- WHERE left(mobile_phone,2)='57' then 'CO'

And based on that logic the table should update AUTOMATICALLY with this information:

| mobile_phone | country |
| --- | --- |
| '51682815' | 'PE' |
| '51261728' | 'PE' |
| '56682815' | 'CL' |
| '56261728' | 'CL' |
| '57682815' | 'CO' |
| '57261728' | 'CO' |

I was thinking to create a trigger like this, but the problem is that I don't know how to create the function that will update the column country:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_country AFTER INSERT ON info
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE function_name()
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Since your records to be updated are already found within your database, you should first use an `UPDATE` statement to update your current rows. You can do it using a `CASE` expression that will assign the "*country*" value conditionally with respect to the "*mobile_phone*".

```
UPDATE "info"
SET country = CASE WHEN LEFT(mobile_phone,2) = '51' THEN 'PE'
                   WHEN LEFT(mobile_phone,2) = '56' THEN 'CL'
                   WHEN LEFT(mobile_phone,2) = '57' THEN 'CO' END;
```

Then create the corresponding trigger, that will update your record before the insertion. It splits into:

- the function "*update_country()*", which returns a trigger that uses `NEW` to access values from the inserting row and update its country value
- the trigger creation definition (which you included in the post as well), that uses "*update_country()*" to update records featured in the insertion statement.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_country()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
'
BEGIN
    NEW.country = CASE WHEN LEFT(NEW.mobile_phone,2) = ''51'' THEN ''PE''
                       WHEN LEFT(NEW.mobile_phone,2) = ''56'' THEN ''CL''
                       WHEN LEFT(NEW.mobile_phone,2) = ''57'' THEN ''CO'' END;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
'
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER update_country_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON "info"
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_country();
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tbgjbWGb3WhLStAFBvYRyt/0).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Generated Columns.
With Generated Columns you can not do
`update info set country =  'x';` or
`insert into info(country) value ('x');`
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html

```
BEGIN;
CREATE temp TABLE info (
    mobile_phone text
    , country text GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( CASE WHEN
    LEFT (mobile_phone , 2) = '51' THEN
        'PE'
    WHEN
    LEFT (mobile_phone , 2) = '52' THEN
        'XY'
    WHEN
    LEFT (mobile_phone , 2) = '53' THEN
        'AB'
    WHEN
    LEFT (mobile_phone , 2) = '54' THEN
        'CD'
    WHEN
    LEFT (mobile_phone , 2) = '55' THEN
        'EF'
    WHEN
    LEFT (mobile_phone , 2) = '56' THEN
        'CL'
    WHEN
    LEFT (mobile_phone , 2) = '57' THEN
        'CO'
    ELSE
        'NA'
    END) STORED
) ON COMMIT DROP;
INSERT INTO info (mobile_phone)
    VALUES ('51682815')
    , ('51261728')
    , ('56682815')
    , ('56261728')
    , ('57682815')
    , ('57261728');
TABLE info;
END;
```